# Creating multiple XMR addresses in a single XMR GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, address

I downloaded the Monero GUI wallet from the [official website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/), extracted all files, opened my `.exe` file, got me the XMR address and finally, successfully sent and received bunch of XMR already.

At this moment, I have a need to create 2-3 additional XMR addresses, but I cannot see this option in GUI wallet itself, like with most of the other wallets, so I wonder how to create additional addresses?

Should I run multiple instances of GUI wallets instead? Or can I use CLI to manage multiple addresses in a single GUI wallet?

The purpose of this is to be able to point my mining rigs to separate addresses and manage incomes in that way, rather than "predicting" the income every month...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subaddresses have now been [merged](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2056) but not yet included in a tagged release. If you build from master, you can use them with the CLI now.

[GUI support](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/pull/793) is still being worked on. Anyone with Qt experienced is encouraged to help!

Depending on your reason for wanting to use more than one address, the `account` [command](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-is-the-account-command-used-in-the-cli) may be a helpful option for you.

Comment: Alright, thanks for quick answer! I updated my question with description of my use case... But let's just clarify your answer... So I **can** use a single `account` which will have multiple `address`es (created with `address new` for my account number `0`), is that right? And I'll be able to use such created addresses to point my mining rigs to each of them and perform normal transactions?

Comment: You can have multiple accounts with multiple subaddresses. Thus you can have account 0 with address A, B + account 1 with address C, D, and E + account 2 with address F. Yes for your last question.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for clarifications and for your answer one more time! ;)

Comment: Note that the change is also in how the sender constructs a TX. So, to actually receive stuff to sub-addresses you'll have to wait for pools to support sending to them. For now, to use multiple wallets with GUI, you must go to Settings, close the current one, and open/create another.